# How to filter SmartCollections via Shopify API?

Tags: node.js, meteor, shopify

I need to get only those SmartCollections that are imitating some kind of category of products e.g. Pants, Shirts, Shoes. But there is also collections like "All Products" or "Available on local store". What I need to get via API are only those spesific categories and nothing else.

So is there any way to set some kind of metafield or alternative to SmartCollections so I could filter via API only collections I need?

Of course one(and really bad) way to do this is to hard code list of not wanted collections, but this solution isn't very dynamic :/

I am using this package [froatsnook:shopify](https://atmospherejs.com/froatsnook/shopify) from atmospherejs.com.
Here is Shopify's API documentation about SmartCollections: [SmartCollection](https://docs.shopify.com/api/smartcollection#index)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to do this eventhough API disagrees with me. With this Chrome extension you can use metafields also with SmartCollections: http://shopifyfd.com/

And then you just have to create new function for this new endpoint via build in functionality provided by [froatsnook:shopify](https://atmospherejs.com/froatsnook/shopify) like this:

```
Shopify.API.define({
    "name": "getSmartCollectionMetafieldsById",
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/admin/smart_collections/#{collection_id}/metafields.json",
    "returns": "metafields",
    "description": "Get a single smart_collection metafields by its ID"
});
```

And voilá! Now you can include/exclude SmartCollections via API by using metafields!